# Change text already displayed on the console

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-console

I have a question about changing text already displayed on the command line window. If I run the command `timeout 10`, the text already displayed on screen would keep on changing. How does this work?

Thanks

Comment: You use the Win32 [console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions).

Comment: Probably it could also be clearing screen and re-printing at the same time.

Comment: @Rishav: That will cause flickering.

Comment: Point. Then you will have to use the console functions.